# Match sql date to fullcalendar for displaying

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, fullcalendar

[image]I'm very new to FullCalendar and I seriously don't know how to adapt it according to my project requirements. Chose it because my Lecturer wants me to. I am aware that fullcalendar is drag and drop function. What i'm trying to do is have an add button for each cell in my fullcalendar page then when I click add it will go to another jsp page (Add Events). Then I have date inputs (java.sql.Date) so this dates must match to full calendar date.I'm So sure that it's some logic here in index.jsp that needs to be done like if and else statement. If mysql date match to fullcalendar date,you display in that cell. Now what it's doing is print out date in every cell from database.And I just need to display the Title. Refer to the pictures attached :)

```
RetrieveServlet: Retrieve from AddEventsServlet (for adding events)
ackage servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import database.DBAO;
import model.AddEvents;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RetrieveServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/RetrieveServlet")
public class RetrieveServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RetrieveServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());


        doPost(request,response); //dispatcher sents deget request, since ur code is in dopost, u will need to all it.
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try
        {
            DBAO myDatabase = new DBAO();
            ArrayList <AddEvents> myEventList = myDatabase.getAddEvents();
            System.out.println(myEventList.size());
            request.setAttribute("EventList",myEventList);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error Accessing Database:" +ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}




AddEventsServlet:
package servlet;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.ListIterator;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import database.DBAO;
import model.AddEvents;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class AddEventsServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/AddEventsServlet")
public class AddEventsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public AddEventsServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //doGet(request, response);


        AddEvents myEvent = new AddEvents();
        //create an object based on the Java class customers
        //DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        //Assignment of data
        myEvent.setTitle(request.getParameter("Title"));
        myEvent.setEventDesc(request.getParameter("EventDesc"));
        myEvent.setStartTime(request.getParameter("StartTime"));
        myEvent.setEndTime(request.getParameter("EndTime"));
        myEvent.setBudget(Double.valueOf(request.getParameter("Budget")));
        myEvent.setStartDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("StartDate")));
        myEvent.setEndDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(request.getParameter("EndDate")));
        myEvent.setEnvironment(request.getParameter("Environment"));


            System.out.println(request.getParameter("Title"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("EventDesc"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("StartTime"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("EndTime"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("Budget"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("StartDate"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("EndDate"));
            System.out.println(request.getParameter("Environment"));


            System.out.println("Title="+myEvent.getTitle());
            System.out.println("EventDesc="+myEvent.getEventDesc());
            System.out.println("StartTime="+myEvent.getStartTime());
            System.out.println("EndTime="+myEvent.getEndTime());
            System.out.println("Budget="+myEvent.getBudget());
            System.out.println("StartDate="+myEvent.getStartDate());
            System.out.println("EndDate="+myEvent.getEndDate());
            System.out.println("Environment="+myEvent.getEnvironment());


        try
        {
            DBAO myDatabase = new DBAO();
            ArrayList <AddEvents> myEventList = myDatabase.getAddEvents(); //not needed
            //AddEvents myEventDetails =myDatabase.isEvent(myEvent,title, eventDesc, StartTime, EndTime, Budget); //not needed

            HttpSession myRequest = request.getSession(true); //not needed
            request.setAttribute("EventList",myEventList); //not needed
            System.out.println(myEventList.size()); //not needed

            // you comment out the method that insert data to database
            myDatabase.AddEvents(myEvent);
            // the dispatcher can go to RetrieveServlet and let it handle the retrieve
            //myDatabase.delete(myEvent,title,eventDesc,StartTime,EndTime,Budget,StartDate,EndDate);
            //name of delete database
            request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error Accessing Database:" +ex);
        }

    }

}
index.jsp: Displaying the full calendar
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<%@page import="model.AddEvents,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.ListIterator" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src= "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">


$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();



    var events_array = [
        {
        title: 'Test1',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 20),
        tip: 'Personal tip 1'},
    {
        title: 'Test2',
        start: new Date(2012, 8, 21),
        tip: 'Personal tip 2'}
    ];

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());

        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);

        alert('Current view: ' + view.name);

        // change the day's background color just for fun
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

    },
        selectable: true,
        events: events_array,
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.attr('title', event.tip);
        }},
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            var d = new Date(dateText);
            $('#fullcalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
        }
    })); 
 function changeDate() {
    var StartDate = $('#datepicker').val();
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', startDate);
}


});


</script>
    <title>Calendar</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

    <a class= "add_event_label" href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea"></a>

    <div class="container">


        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12">

                <h1>Calendar</h1>


                <div id="bootstrapModalFullCalendar"></div>





            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

  <!-- this is the pop up window when you press the button -->

   <div id="fullCalModal" class="modal fade">

        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>

                    <h4 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title"></h4>

                </div>

                <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">


                 </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="eventUrl" target="_blank">Event Page</a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.2/moment.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <script>


        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({

                header: {

                    left: '',

                    center: 'prev title next',

                    right: ''


                },


                //action after calendar loaded
                eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
                    if(view.name == 'month')
                    {                       
                        //loop all .fc-day elements
                        $('.fc-day').each(function(){
                        //jQuery styling
                            $(this).css({ 'font-weight': 'bold', 'font-size': '100%'});
                            $(this).css('position','relative');
                            //add elements to each .fc-day, you can modify the content in append() with your own html button code


                            $(this).append('<a class="add_event_label" onclick="changeDate()" href ="AddEvent.jsp" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;display:block;font-size:12px;color:blue;cursor:pointer;">(+)</a>' );

                            <%!ArrayList<AddEvents> myEventList; //have to declear in a declaration tag for access in the page %>
                            <% myEventList = (ArrayList<AddEvents>) request.getAttribute("EventList");
                            if(myEventList.size() == 0)
                            {
                                %>
                                <h2>No events</h2>
                                <%
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                %>


                            <%
                            ListIterator<AddEvents> li = myEventList.listIterator();

                            while(li.hasNext())
                            {


                                AddEvents myEvent = new AddEvents();
                                myEvent= (AddEvents)li.next();


                                %>
                            //This part it should add data according to date, now it's just adding all the data of title.

                            $(this).append('<p><font size="1">Title:</font></p><p><font size="1"><%= myEvent.getTitle() %></font></p></p>');
                            <%}

                                %>

                                <%
                                }
                                %>



                        });      
                    }                   
                },

                eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    //$(".fc-day-number").prepend("(+) ");

                    $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);

                    $('#modalBody').html(event.description);

                    $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);

                    $('#fullCalModal').modal();


                    return false;

                }



            })
            })

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you asking how to compare the java dates and fullcalendar event date ? wht is ur question, pleas b clear

Comment: sorry i think the explaination that ive put below got hidden. Edited the post now so pls take a look :) Thank you

Comment: fullcalendar need only the event source with start date and title, it will fill the calendar automatically, u need to pass the sql data to event obj,ok

Comment: Erm, that's the part I don't know how to do....

Comment: u need to know hoe topass the jsp variable to javascript first, create an event variable as a date variable and title string, set the value from jsp. add the event var to eventSources of fullcalendar..